# Unable to read property with a cloud function in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've a cloud firebase function that get triggered from Firestore when a document is added to a collection. I'm having a problem parsing the json.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'venue' of undefined
    at exports.updateCollectionCount.functions.firestore.document.onWrite (/workspace/index.js:136:24)
```

I'm really not familiar with JS so I presume my syntax might be wrong or maybe missing some `async` `keyword` because sometimes the parsing works fine. I'm looking to get the id value in the venue map.

```
exports.updateCollectionCount = functions.firestore
        .document('orders/{order}')
        .onWrite((change, context) => {
    
           let map = change.after.data();
           console.log(map);
    
            let venue = map['venue'];  /// here is where my error is (line 36)
            console.log(venue);
       const venueId =  venue['id'];
       let orderType = map['orderType'];
    
       if(orderType === 'Collection'){


            db.collection('venues').doc(`${venueId}`).update({"collectionCount":admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)})
       }
     return;
    
    });
```

[image]

Comment: try changing `let map=change.after.data()` to `let map=await change.after.data()`

Comment: intellisense says that won't make any difference

Comment: i take it that means u *tried* and it didnt work?

Comment: I'll try it now(intellisense are hints from the editor)